# encounter error during deeplab v3+ training on Cityscapes Semantic Segmentation Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, semantic-segmentation

all,

I start the training process using deeplab v3+ following this [guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/cityscapes.md). However, after step 1480, I got the error:

```
Error reported to Coordinator: Nan in summary histogram for: image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance_2
```

The detailed train log is [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/amiltonwong/ef0befefdd7dd618983e94252057cb8c/raw/96855c4962da6be3c8ee63a0acaa29bd62d2167f/detail_log)

Could someone suggest how to solve this issue?  THX!

Comment: I use TF1.6 in my system

Answer (score 7):

Based on the log, it seems that you are training with batch_size = 1, fine_tune_batch_norm = True (default value). Since you are fine-tuning batch norm during training, it is better to set batch size as large as possible (see [comments](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/train.py#L93) in train.py and Q5 in [FAQ](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/faq.md)). If only limited GPU memory is available, you could fine-tune from the provided pre-trained checkpoint, set **smaller learning rate** and **fine_tune_batch_norm = False** (see [model_zoo.md](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md) for details). Note make sure the flag tf_initial_checkpoint has correct path to the desired pre-trained checkpoint.

Comment: What would you consider "limited GPU memory"? I am using a GTX 1060 with 6GB of dedicated memory and get the same error. Do you think that using MobileNet instead of Xception would allow me to train locally?

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same accuracy with a small batch_size, perhaps by training longer? With ~18GB of memory between two GPUs I'm only able to fit 2 batches in memory it seems